# Sencha Windows Native App Packaging Support?

Tags: windows, sencha-touch, native, packaging

Can anyone help me to confirm whether the latest Sencha Touch / Command is having the support for Windows Native App Packaging, similar to iPhone & Android.

Thanks in Advance.
Asuthosh

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Cmd has integration with Cordova and PhoneGap, which support a variety of Windows platforms. So indirectly the answer is yes.